# Android: disable setting which keeps device screen on when plugged in

Tags: android, screen, user-inactivity

How can I disable the development setting which prevents screen from turning off when plugged in?

Basically I want to detect user inactivity on an Android device by detecting when screen goes off, but if this setting is enabled this will never happen. 
From what I found, `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission should be used (rooting device/using private APIs is not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);
```